# cin and cin.ignore() doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, iostream, cin

I have trouble with cin and cin.ignore(). This is my code and it doesn't have any error but it doesn't work properly. when I want to see the ID results it shows me something weird.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class watchTower {
private:
    int numberOfAirplane;
    int runway;
    int numberOfOrders;
    string menu;
    char ID[][11];


public:
    void setNumberOfAirplane(int n) { numberOfAirplane = n;}
    void setRunWay(int k) { runway = k;}
    void setID(char id[][11]);
    void setNumberOfOrders(int q) { numberOfOrders = q;}
    void display();
};


void watchTower::display() {
    cout << numberOfAirplane << ' ' << runway << ' ' << numberOfOrders << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfAirplane; i++)
        cout << ID[i] << endl;

}

void watchTower::setID(char (*id)[11]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfAirplane; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
            ID[i][j] = id[i][j];
}



int main() {
    int n, k, q;
    cin >> n >> k;
    char id[n][11];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin.ignore(256, '\n');
        cin >> id[i];
        cin.clear();

    }
    watchTower input;
    input.setNumberOfAirplane(n);
    input.setRunWay(k);
    input.setID(id);
    cin >> q;
    input.setNumberOfOrders(q);
    input.display();
}
```

As you can see I tried both cin.ignore and cin.clear but they don't work.
by the way these are my inputs.

> 3 4
> 0000000001
> 0000000002
> 0000000003
> 5

and these are my outputs which are incorrect.

> 3 4 5
> 0000000001
> 0♣
> 0000000003

Comment: Get rid of those calls to `cin.ignore` and `cin.clear`. Three's nothing in the code that requires them.

Comment: if I don't use cin.ignore(), it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, there are other problems. Focus on therm. In particular, `char ID[][11]` is a monstrosity. `std::vector<std::string> ID;` would be much easier to use.

Comment: but I've seen it can work. I think it relates to cin. but thank you.

Comment: `char id[n][11];` is **not** valid standard-C++ code. Why are you using `char` arrays instead of `string`? At no point to you initialize `ID`'s first dimension in the `watchTower`, that I can see .... how big is it?

Comment: `cin >> n >> k;  char id[n][11];` This is not valid C++ code. Do yourself a huge favour and don't try to learn C++ from random places you find on the internet. Get a good book instead, and adopt sane coding practices. Here's the first one: *always* (no excuses)  use `-Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors`.

Comment: for this dimension, I get it from input.

Comment: No, you just think you do :) `numberOfAirplane` is NOT the dimension.

Comment: `char ID[][11];` is a C programming trick called a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). While some C++ compilers have extensions to allow them, you have to be awesomely careful using those extensions.

Comment: You use `cin.clear()` to remove error flags on the input stream. This is generally a bad idea unless you've already tested the stream and found you have an error and have already resolved this error. As Pete Becker hints above, throwing `clear`s and `ignore`s in willy-nilly without good cause does nothing but HIDE errors that you should be trapping and handling. And errors you do not handle correctly become bugs.

Comment: @user4581301 - a FAM only exists as the last member of a struct. The is nothing but an incomplete type.

Comment: Here's a cut down example of what is going on: https://godbolt.org/z/3vjzKso4a . Note how `input` did not change size after the code sets the number of airplanes. An object in C++ cannot change size. The size is determined by the `class`, and the `class` only has one size. There is no way to ask for more space for an array in a `watchTower` If there is no space for the array, you can't write stuff into the array.

Comment: Here's your code again compiled with extra diagnostics to tell you what went wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/xrMxM16jx. The important stuff is **stack-buffer-overflow** and **in watchTower::setID(char (*) [11]) /app/example.cpp:34** because they tell you what happened and exactly where. Line 34 is `ID[i][j] = id[i][j];` The program tried to write to `ID` and `ID` has no storage.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If `watchTower` was a C struct, `ID` would be the last member, and it's almost certainly support for FAM that is allowing the asker's code to compile.

Comment: @user4581301 -- yep, I noticed that `:)` (but classes are their own animal)

Comment: `char id[n][11];` is _not_ standard C++. And your bug is (…drumroll…): `char ID[][11];`. What storage is behind that “dynamic” array? Recommendation: Don’t use weird C99 constructs in C++, even if compilers let you. Even in C99 you would have some serious calculations to do to allocate a `watchTower` correctly (given its size). Use STL containers instead.